# From QMake to CMake. (Different path levels)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm trying to port a multilevel project from QMake to CMake. (I try to make it work a simple example first)

Below show I the desired structure:

The location of the root CMakeLists.txt a path level before than the main and the lib is a requirement

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── app02
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
└── lib
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── myprint.cpp
    └── myprint.h
```

The root CMakeLists.txt is so written:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME "testProject")
project(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/enigma/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
set(QT5_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)

add_subdirectory(lib app02)

set(TARGET "app02Build")
add_executable(${TARGET} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${TARGET} thePrintLibrary ${QT5_LIBRARIES})
```

The main.cpp in app002 path is written so:

```
#include "../lib/myprint.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myPrint::print("This the second App");
}
```

And here is its correspondig CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)
```

The lib path contains the next files:

myprint.h

```
#ifndef MYPRINT_H
#define MYPRINT_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <string>

class myPrint
{
public:
    static void print(std::string toPrint) {
        qDebug() << toPrint.c_str();
    }
};

#endif // MYPRINT_H
```

myPrint.cpp

```
#include "myprint.h"
//yes, there is no more code :-)
```

and the corresponding CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
    
add_library( 
    thePrintLibrary
    myprint.h
    myprint.cpp
)
```

The CMake prescan runs fine, but when I compile I become the next error:

```
[ 28%] Building CXX object app02/CMakeFiles/thePrintLibrary.dir/myprint.cpp.o
In file included from /home/enigma/APD_Programas/Port/test/lib/myprint.cpp:1:
/home/enigma/APD_Programas/Port/test/lib/myprint.h:4:10: fatal error: QDebug: No such file or directory
 #include <QDebug>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [app02/CMakeFiles/thePrintLibrary.dir/build.make:63: app02/CMakeFiles/thePrintLibrary.dir/myprint.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:162: app02/CMakeFiles/thePrintLibrary.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Someone so kind to help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need Qt5::Core in addition to Qt5::Widgets

Comment: Thank you, I did it but don't change the result :-(

Answer (score 1):

Has drescherjm say it in the comment, you're missing Qt5::Core in your target_link_libraries

first add :

```
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
```

then replace :

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} thePrintLibrary ${QT5_LIBRARIES})
```

by

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} thePrintLibrary ${QT5_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Core)
```

or replace

```
set(QT5_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)
```

by

```
set(QT5_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core)
```

Comment: I think you also will need a find_package() for Qt5Core

Comment: Hi, and thank you. I don't know why my answer is in the top than yours, I'm new in the forum. Thank you very much, I did it, but i get the same error :-(

Comment: have you added the line  'find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)'
 ?

Comment: I added:   find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core)
set(QT5_LIBRARIES Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)  .... Produces the same error :-(

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both,

but when I replace the lines for:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core)
set(QT5_LIBRARIES Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)
```

I become the same error :-(

```
[ 28%] Building CXX object app02/CMakeFiles/thePrintLibrary.dir/myprint.cpp.o
In file included from /home/enigma/APD_Programas/Port/test/lib/myprint.cpp:1:
/home/enigma/APD_Programas/Port/test/lib/myprint.h:4:10: fatal error: QDebug: No such file or directory
 #include <QDebug>
```

I tried to add the next sentence too: (because I suspect that the library don't link right to Qt)

```
target_link_libraries(thePrintLibrary ${QT5_LIBRARIES})
```

then I get the next weird error on final linking:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable app02Build
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/app02Build.dir/build.make:88: app02Build] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:74: CMakeFiles/app02Build.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: You are not supposed to ask questions when you provide an answer which is supposed to be the solution to the question. Instead if it is a different problem than the original question you probably need to ask a completely new question. In either case its difficult to help because you have no small example. You could have reproduced the error for the original question with a small Qt program that only includes a singe file and an int main() a single CMakeLists.txt to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: `(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'` is the file containing your `int main()` listed in the sources. I think you are missing an add_subdirectory() for where ever the CMakeLists.txt file is that adds main.cpp to SOURCES

Comment: I'm new to the forum and I was a bit confused, pardon me. I had not problem with a simple file. The problem come on that tree structure. I have written the code of all files. I don't know if could I attach a .zip with the code in the forum, so here is:  https://easyupload.io/k4wc8a

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,
I found the last fail, with your help.

In that path distribution, I must supply the complete main path in add_executable.

```
add_executable(${TARGET} app02/main.cpp)
```

Perhaps is there a better solution, so, if somebody want add something,
please, you're wellcomed